# How to have divs with same space-around for both sides using flex-wrap ? - Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i don't understand why my CSS3 not works...

I have 4 `div` and i want to adapt them to width of device.
Divs are same size so i use `flexbox` to do this.

Using `flex-wrap: wrap` move divs on more lines while using `justify-content: space-around` i want to have same distance for each line (where there are divs) for both sides.

But doesn't work...

[image]

This is **HTML**

```
<div id="rossi">
    <div id="title-rossi">Rossi</div>
    <div id="vini-rossi">
            <a href="/collezione-vini/il-nibbio-grigio">
            <div id="nibbio-grigio">
                <div id="img-nibbio-grigio">
                </div>
            <div id="nome-nibbio-grigio">Il Nibbio grigio</div>
            </div> 
            </a> 
            <a href="/collezione-vini/tenute-piano-regio">          
            <div id="tenute-piano-regio">
                <div id="img-tenute-piano-regio">
                </div>
            <div id="nome-tenute-piano-regio">Tenute Piano Regio</div>
            </div>
            </a> 
            <a href="/collezione-vini/tenute-san-savino"> 
            <div id="tenute-san-savino">
                <div id="img-tenute-san-savino">
                </div>
                <div id="nome-tenute-san-savino">Tenute San Savino</div>
            </div>
            </a>
            <a href="/collezione-vini/kline-rosso">  
            <div id="kline-rosso">
                <div id="img-kline-rosso">
                </div>
            <div id="nome-kline-rosso">Kline Rosso</div>
            </div>
            </a>
     </div>
   </div>
```

I created a jsfiddle example:  https://jsfiddle.net/4960h32L/

My problem is when `@media (max-width: 416px)` so in jsfiddle (or in local test) the window must be short.

`#vini-rossi` has `flex-wrap: wrap` and when max-width of screen is **416px** i add also `justify-content: space-around`

Comment: This is not possible unless each div has the same defined width. Flexbox cannot equalise widths between *rows*.

Comment: @Paulie_D yes in my case each div has the same width. How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has to do with the wine's name being larger, thus "pushing" the image a bit

Comment: So what is the issue...it's not clear?

Comment: @Paulie_D have same distance for both sides using space-around ....

Comment: @IvanS95 no the problem isn't the wine's name... :(

Comment: You're just restating the question without explaining what is actually happening. Your fiddle does not seem to show the problem.

Comment: i paste an image with the problem... i ask you: is possibile that using space-around we don't have same distance for both sides ?

Comment: @Paulie_D what I can see in OPs post is that in the first row, the bottle image on the right has more space to its right than the left image to its left; so they don't look "evenly" distributed

Comment: exactly! I assure you that the code on the site and the code entered in jsfiddle are identical.

Comment: Then something else is going on. I'd suggest the *links* should have a fixed width...not the divs.

Comment: I understand... my cms (Drupal) convert each new line in html (<br>) so in the code (of website) i had <br>. Deleting its now is correct. Sorry